# Protein Domain Boundary Prediction

Tags: deep-learning, bioinformatics

To perform analysis on protein sequence using deep learning, sequences have to be encoded in numeric representation.

Considering ability of deep learning models to extract features automatically, different non biological encoding schemes also have been used for example amino acid compositional information, frequencies of amino acids in sequence and one hot encoding.

I want to know that binary representation can be used to encode protein sequences. For instance, [0,0,0,0,1] and [0,0,0,1,0] are representations of two amino acids.

To encode 21 unique amino acids minimum five binary digits are required.

Comment: I'm not exactly sure what you're asking, but if you are asking if one-hot encoding works, the answer is yes. If you want to read more about other encoding schemes using the python category encoders package, I wrote an a guide here: https://towardsdatascience.com/smarter-ways-to-encode-categorical-data-for-machine-learning-part-1-of-3-6dca2f71b159?source=friends_link&sk=b2875c95d2c13fa92a652269cba99d7d